# Adding Options To Select In HTML From Jquery Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, phonegap

The Options Are Not Added To Html Select From Jquery. Please Tell Me Where Am I Wrong?
1. My HTML CODE

```
<div id="kkr">
  <select id="studenttags" class="mdb-select colorful-select dropdown-primary" multiple searchable="Search here.." required>
    <option value="0" disabled selected>Tag Classes / Sections</option>
    <!-- <option value="1" data-icon="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Avatars/avatar-1.jpg" class="rounded-circle">Section-Mountain</option>
    <option value="2" data-icon="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Avatars/avatar-1.jpg" class="rounded-circle">Section-River</option>
    <option value="3" data-icon="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Avatars/avatar-1.jpg" class="rounded-circle">Section-Forest</option>
    <option value="4" data-icon="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Avatars/avatar-1.jpg" class="rounded-circle">Section-Idiots</option>
    <option value="5" data-icon="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Avatars/avatar-1.jpg" class="rounded-circle">Section-Goods</option> -->
  </select>
</div>
```

2. My JQUERY CODE

   ```
   $.each(data.result, function(i, field)
   {
    console.log(field.class_name);
    // $('#studenttags').append('<option value="'+field.id+'">'+field.class_name+field.class_nick_name+'['+field.enrolled_year+']'+'</option>');
    // $('#studenttags').append("<option>BMW</option>");
    // $('#studenttags').append($('<option>', {value:1, text:'One'}));
    // $("#studenttags").append('<option value="option6">option6</option>');
    // $('#studenttags').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",i).text(field.class_name)); 
   });
   ```

None Of The Above Commented Line Worked.

Comment: what is `data.result` and what values you are receiving? have you called this function inside `document.ready` to ensure if all DOM is ready?

Comment: Works fine if it's run without the `.each` loop:  https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/4fnubcdq/1/

Comment: Your "append" commands are working. But I guess you can't see the expected result because you are using MDB wrapper for select it has to be updated after underlying select is changed. Look how to do it in the documentation for MDB.

Comment: Yes I am receiving data from line ->console.log(field.class_name);
But Option append is not working.

Comment: @wanjas : Thanks Man..... I've read MDB select documentation and got it working..... Thank You Very Much... Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From The Comment Above From @wanjas,
 I read the MDB select documentation and found that problem is not with my jquery but it is with handling MDB select append from jquery and found that correct way to do it is:-

```
                //Step-1: Destroy MDB Select
                //Step-2: Add all Options
                //Step-3: Initialize MDB Select
                $('.mdb-select').material_select('destroy');
                $.each(data.result, function(i, field){
                $('#studenttags').append('<option value="'+field.id+'">'+field.class_name+"-"+field.class_nick_name+'['+field.enrolled_year+' Intake]'+'</option>');
                });
                $('.mdb-select').material_select();
```

Once Again Thank You Very Much @wanjas.
 Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can add the option to the select in a more dynamic way. If you are using jQuery, you can let it handle the html syntax for you.

```js
// Mocking your data object. We dontknow your object structure

var data = {
  result: [{
    class_name: 'some-class-name',
    id: 1,
    class_nick_name: 'some-nick-name',
    enrolled_year: 2018
  }]
};



$.each(data.result, function(i, field) {
  console.log(field.class_name);
  var newOption = $('<option>', {
    value: field.id
  });

  newOption.html(field.class_name + field.class_nick_name + '[' + field.enrolled_year + ']');

  newOption.appendTo('#studenttags');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="kkr">
  <select id="studenttags" class="mdb-select colorful-select dropdown-primary" multiple searchable="Search here.." required>
    <option value="0" disabled selected>Tag Classes / Sections</option>

  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much @Mr. Brickowski for your answer...... Really appericiate it.... 

I got the solution, problem was from mdb-select class. And I Fixed It after reading MDB Select Documentation.....

I am very thankful to you...

Cheers!!!